# EventHandlerBehavior vs EventToCommandBehavior

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms what is the difference between the EventHandlerBehavior and EventToCommandBehavior?  I have been using the former successfully, but the latter was suggested to me to use instead.  EventToCommandBehavior is less verbose which is a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About difference between EventHandlerBehavior and EventToCommandBehavior, I have some point, you can take a look:

For **EventHandlerBehavior**, you need to install **Behaviors.Forms** in your project firstly, behaviors let you add functionality to controls without having to subclass them. Instead, the functionality is implemented in a behavior class and attached to the control as if it was part of the control itself. Behaviors enable you to implement code that you would normally have to write as code-behind, because it directly interacts with the API of the control in such a way that it can be concisely attached to the control and packaged for reuse across more than one app.

For **EventToCommandBehavior**,the EventToCommandBehavior is a custom class, there are need you create EventToCommandBehavior class derives from the BehaviorBase class firstly, then implementing Bindable Properties, for detailed info, you can take a look:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior

So I suggest you can use EventHandlerBehavior, because you don't need to create many code behind.

#### 2021 Edit

EventHandlerBehavior from community-toolkit is now equivalent to EventHandlerBehavior.

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior

Comment: Thanks Cherry.  The Behaviors.Forms nuget is no longer needed in XF 4!  It was needed prior however.

Comment: To be more precise, you can now use [Xamarin Community Toolkit EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior)

Answer (score 1):

> In Xamarin Forms what is the difference between the EventHandlerBehavior and EventToCommandBehavior?

Eventhandler like:
OnTextChanged, OnSelectedIndexChanged etc are defined behind the C# code file of XAML. These methods are completely tied to your controls you define behind your pages/controls.

However the Behaviors in Xamarin allows us to ATTACH them to any View. Your behavior will know which controls it is being attached to. Hence, for those Events like OnTextChanged/OnSelectedIndexChanged can be controlled from the Behaviors.

EventToCommandBehaivor: As we already know that Behavior get attached to any view; you have to define the behavior as such that It will expose the BINDABLE property for Commands. EventToCommandBehavior is just a normal behavior control which supports binding the Command and the Eventname. Which in runtime, whenever the Event for the control get fired, your behavior will execute the Command attached making it more ViewModel friendly.

Remember if you use Events; you are writing them behind the code base than ViewModel your logics are in two separate places. If you want to properly separate the logics from View and Model then then you have to use EventToCommandBehavior.

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually understand what behaviors are.  I was just asking what the difference was between the two.  Also, I updated my question to remove the extra questions I had (I am past that issue now).  It seems they both accomplish the same thing, but the EventToCommand is more concise (less verbose).

Comment: Prime difference between them - Event Handlers are not Bindable but EventsToCommands you make them Bindable. Events you write behind code base, Events to Command you write your logics (Command) in ViewModel !